# Dynamically load tabs corresponding to particular Node into View onclick of a node AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have ten nodes which are coded using DRAG and Drop and after Drop, on click of the node i want to display tabs corresponding to the node dynamically, as all the tabs are not required for all the nodes. now i am displaying the tabs from a controller common for all the nodes.. but i want to disply tabs corresponding to each node.
Thanks for the help in advance..

```
<div id="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl" ng-hide="!IsVisible">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
ng-click="onClickTab(tab)"><a>{{tab.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="mainView">
<div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

my Controller for the tabs is:

```
app.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.tabs = [
{title: 'Item',url: 'item.html'},
{title: 'Bom',url: 'two.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Sourcing Rule',url:'three.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Item Attributes',url: 'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Categories',url: 'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Cross Refrences',url: 'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Effective Categories',url:'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'DIN',url: 'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Coustomer Limit',url: 'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'CICR',url:'one.tpl.html'}, 
{title: 'Co-Products',url:'one.tpl.html'},
{title: 'Org Assign',url: 'one.tpl.html'}];

$scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';
$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
  $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
}
$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
  return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
}]);
```

Comment: your snippet load template onclick, See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soeuhLdf/) , so what your exact expected behaviour.?

Comment: this loads onclick of one node, i want the list to be updated depending on the node which is being clicked and the list elements vary depending on each node